# ajax call success not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have a res.json(data) object returned in nodejs when called to '/json-endpoint'. Want to display the result to frontend. Can't seems to get it right.

When i changed the below line 
from 
strHTMLOutput = data;
to
strHTMLOutput = 'Yeah! its working';

my #enquiries changed to 'Yeah! its working'

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var strHTMLOutput = '';
//Make a ajax call to fetch data
$.ajax({
    url: '/json-endpoint',
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",

    error: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
    },
    success: function (data) {
        strHTMLOutput = data;
        $('#enquiries').html(strHTMLOutput);
        console.log('it is working');
    }



});
});
```

Comment: just a note, your contentType option doesn't make much sense. you aren't sending data to the server, so the default content type is fine.

Comment: If you don't make the change suggested, what does it output to #enquiries?

Comment: thank you kevin. If i do  strHTMLOutput = data;     $('#enquiries').html(strHTMLOutput); Nothing is showing / changing in frontend.

Comment: `data` should be a JavaScript object presenting the JSON object. This will result in "[object Object]" being displayed in the HTML.

Comment: It should still be giving "[object Object]", not nothing.

Comment: Actually, if the server is returning an empty array, a stringified empy array is "". so, that's likely the culprit.

Comment: @Alex your server isn't returning any data, therefore nothing is displaying. there's nothing wrong with your client-side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with your code. The success callback is being fired, and you're correctly outputting the result into the page. However, since the result is empty, you're not seeing any change.

Therefore, the problem is with your server, not the client-side code.

Comment: on the server side. after i queried the database , i res.json(result) and it is showing up in the console. When i used the ajax call in frontend . nothing showing up . Thank you guys. i am all new to this.

Comment: I suspect `result` is an empty array. There's no other possible way you would get to the success callback and still be getting an empty string printed to the html without entering the error callback.

Comment: Look at it this way. The only possible way to get into the success callback when you specify `dataType: 'json'` is if the server properly returns json with a 200 or 304 status code. Now, if what you say is true, you did get to the success callback, and printing a hardcoded string to the html works, therefore, the only possible way for you to get the result your getting is if the server is returning a json string that when stringified results in an empty string, and an empty array is the only case when that happens.

Comment: it is working after i do this : var jsonresult = JSON.stringify(result) on server side. Thank you!